# Equivalent statement on Cauchy sequence

Tags: analysis, cauchy-sequences

There are three statements that I need to show their equivalence:

> (i) Every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges to a limit in $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> (ii) Every monotone and bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges to a limit in $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> (iii) Every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a sub-sequence that converges to a limit in $\mathbb{R}$.

---

What I have thought of so far is:

1. Every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded. Thus, a limit exists in $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Because it is bounded, it has a sub-sequence using Monotone Subsequence Theorem.
3. Then, if a sub-sequence of a Cauchy sequence converges to a limit in $\mathbb{R}$, it implies that the Cauchy sequence itself also converges to the same limit.

In the above draft, are there any flaws? In fact, I read some materials before I figure this relation. Is it enough to show these three statements are equivalent? If not, what did I miss??

Comment: You are suppose to prove the equivalence of the three properties of $\mathbb R$ but you are attempting to prove each of the three properties.

Comment: The flaw in your drafts is that I (the reader) don't know what you are proving in each of the points. In 1., are you proving that statement (i) follows from statement (ii)?

Comment: You have to show that $1\implies 2$, $2\implies 3$ and $3\implies 1$

Comment: What I mean in the above is I try to show "iii" $\longrightarrow$ "i" using "3". And show "ii" $\longrightarrow$ "iii" using "2". "i" $\longrightarrow$ "ii" using "1".